# Convert value in timediff() into string for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have a query to get hour between times. For example, I get the results 1:50 from the query.

```
select TIMEDIFF(time_start,time_end) hours from booking_submit
```

How to convert value in timediff() into something like '1 hours 50 minutes'?

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT` will help [check](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use date functions:

```
select time_format(timediff(time_start,time_end), '%H hours %i minutes') as hours
from booking_submit
```

Comment: This works but why some of them are negative value.

Comment: @AmirulFahmi: actually the argument of `time_diff()` should be the other way around: `timediff(time_endtime_start)` (I did not pay attention to the column names when I copy/pasted this part of your query).

Comment: I also didnt notice at first. But this really works and simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your question

```
SELECT CONCAT(
MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(time_start, time_end)), 24), ' Hours ',
MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(time_start, time_end)), ' Minutes '
) time_spent
FROM booking_submit;
```

As far as time_start is within 24 hours of time_end. Otherwise, will give you the time from the start time to the end time regardless of the date.
If you want to add the days spent you may add to the CONCAT function something like:

```
CONCAT(FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(time_start, time_end)) / 24), ' Days ',
```

Hope it'll work for you.